# How to display master related data in C# gridview using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and stuck on displaying the detailed records of the master table.

I have a `MasterBindingSource` and `DetailsBindingSource` along with two `DataGridView`s on the form.

What I'm trying to do is: fill the `detailsGridView` related to the selected data on the `masterGridView`.

Can anyone guide me through this please?

This is what I've done, I'm able to fill the masterGridview but details table are not filled related to the master...

```
MasterTbBindingSource.DataSource = lobo.MasterTb.Include("DetailTb").ToList();
```

What am I missing? Thanks

***UPDATE***

```
public partial class CONTACTS_BASE//Master
{
    public CONTACTS_BASE()
    {
        this.ORDERS = new HashSet<ORDER>();
    }

    public int CB_REFNO { get; set; }
    public string CB_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CB_ID_NO { get; set; }
    public string CB_AGE { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ORDER> ORDERS { get; set; }
}

public partial class ORDER //Detail
{
    public int OR_REFNO { get; set; }
    public string OR_PROD_CODE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OR_M_REFNO { get; set; }

    public virtual CONTACTS_BASE CONTACTS_BASE { get; set; }
}
```

and this is what I tried to achive my goal:

```
using (var lobo = new MyEfTestEntities())
{
            CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource.DataSource = lobo.CONTACTS_BASE.Include("ORDERS").ToList();

            ORDERBindingSource.DataSource = CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource;
            ORDERBindingSource.DataMember = "ORDERS";  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unrelated to Entity Framework. Automatic Master - Details synchronization of two `DataGridView` controls with `BindingSource` components is quite easy. All you need is to set the master `BindingSource` as `DataSource` of the detail `BindingSource` and use the `DataMember` of the detail `BindingSource` to specify the name of the detail collection.

Something like this:

```
MasterTbBindingSource.DataSource = lobo.MasterTb.Include("DetailTb").ToList();
DetailsBindingSource.DataSource = MasterTbBindingSource;
DetailsBindingSource.DataMember = "DetailTb";
```

Comment: when I do bind the DetailsDataGridView like this, Count and IsReadOnly(CheckBox) are only fields I see on the DataGridView, What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: Well, what you see depends on what bindable properties have your classes. Can you update the question with the master and detail entity models (classes)?

Comment: Just made an edit to my question with actual classes

Comment: Looks like WF data binding does not like `ICollection` and `HashSet`. Try changing them respectively to `IList` and `List`, or consider creating special classes (a.k.a. view models).

Comment: When I use this i have the following exception: `System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type`